# Struts File Upload Error

Tags: struts

i have problem when i am uploading file using struts i have some problem like

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.invokeMethod(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1773)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.setSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1759)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.setNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1648)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.setProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1677)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.setProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:1022)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.populate(BeanUtilsBean.java:811)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.populate(BeanUtils.java:298)
    at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.populate(RequestUtils.java:493)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processPopulate(RequestProcessor.java:816)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:203)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:261)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:581)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Jun 30, 2011 5:30:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet action threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot invoke com.employer.generateResume.GenerateResumeForm.setAttachFile - argument type mismatch
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.invokeMethod(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1778)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.setSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1759)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.setNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1648)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.setProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1677)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.setProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:1022)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.populate(BeanUtilsBean.java:811)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.populate(BeanUtils.java:298)
    at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.populate(RequestUtils.java:493)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processPopulate(RequestProcessor.java:816)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:203)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:261)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:581)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Jun 30, 2011 5:31:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig checkResources
INFO: Reloading context [/company]
Jun 30, 2011 5:32:08 PM org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean invokeMethod
SEVERE: Method invocation failed.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.invokeMethod(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1773)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.setSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1759)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.setNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1648)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.setProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1677)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.setProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:1022)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.populate(BeanUtilsBean.java:811)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.populate(BeanUtils.java:298)
    at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.populate(RequestUtils.java:493)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processPopulate(RequestProcessor.java:816)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:203)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:261)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:581)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Jun 30, 2011 5:32:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet action threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot invoke com.employer.generateResume.GenerateResumeForm.setAttachFile - argument type mismatch
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.invokeMethod(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1778)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.setSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1759)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.setNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1648)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.setProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1677)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.setProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:1022)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.populate(BeanUtilsBean.java:811)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.populate(BeanUtils.java:298)
    at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.populate(RequestUtils.java:493)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processPopulate(RequestProcessor.java:816)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:203)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:261)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:581)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Comment: a) It's next to impossible to solve your problem without looking at your code. b) You haven't accepted any of the answers on any of the 19 previous questions you've asked.

Comment: Posting some of your own code, in addition to the error, would be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Removing the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute from my struts form tag results in a similar error for me, so forgetting to include that may be your issue.

Comment: it says enctype is an undefined attribute. will it work in struts1?